# How can I update all records in an Inventory Table to add "/invent" to the beginning of an existing file path using a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to add "/invent" at the beginning of the file path in the invImage and invThumbnail columns.

This is what I have in mind,

```
SELECT FROM inventory 
SELECT CONCAT("/invent")
AS invImage, invThumbnail;
```

Since it is not easy to undo mistakes in SQL, a confirmation of my potential solution will be helpful.

Comment: `Since it is not easy to undo mistakes`...start a transaction, do the operation, look at the result, roll back transaction

Comment: Why've you edited it to show a query which isn't even an UPDATE? It makes even less sense, your original version was much closer to what's needed. I suggest rolling back the change. I already answered based on your original version - see below

Comment: @ ADyson, I was looking at it and thought this was more appropriate because I had to use the Concat function. I was wrong. Your answer solved the problem.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote it then, if that's the case - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current version will overwrite the value in the `invImage` column, but your stated goal is to

a) prepend the string to the existing value, and

b) do this in two columns, not just one

`WHERE invImage = "/images";` also won't match any of the rows, because none of them contain exactly that value. I'll assume you want to update all rows whose `invImage` value *starts* with "/images".

Therefore, try this:

```
UPDATE 
  inventory 
SET 
  invImage = CONCAT("/invent", invImage),
  invThumbnail = CONCAT("/invent", invThumbnail),
WHERE 
  invImage LIKE "/images%";
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: add temporarily two columns to the table: `tmp_invImage` and `tmp_invThumbnail`.

Then run the query:

```
UPDATE table SET 
tmp_invImage = CONCAT("/invent",invImage),
tmp_invThumbnail = CONCAT("/invent",invThumbnail)
```

After the update, look if the values of `tmp_invImage` and `tmp_invThumbnail` are correct.

Then update the original columns:

```
UPDATE table SET 
invImage = tmp_invImage),
invThumbnail = tmp_invThumbnail
```

and delete the `tmp_` columns.